# How to do map in an array of objects that value is an array? Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to do a `map` of an array, but it doesn't work, it is array of objects but the values the objects is an array..

Example:

```js
   itemsToFilter = [{
    "domain_name": [
      "Sales and Marketing Systems",
      "Finance and Supply Chain",
      "Global Infrastructure & CIO Services",
      "Systems and Tools",
      "Quote to Cash & Services",
      "Network Engineering",
      "CFO",
      "Cloud, Collaboration, Support & Identity",
      "Digital Workplace Engineering",
      "CIO Design",
      "Confidential",
      "CIO Domain"
    ]
  },
  {
    "subdomain_name": [
      "Territory, Quota and Coverage",
      "Analytics@IBM",
      "CIO Business Development",
      "HW/SW Manufacturing and Plan to Supply",
      "Virtualisation and Data Center Platforms",
      "HR Talent & Travel IT",
      "Quote to Cash and Services",
      "Finance",
      "CIO Services Japan",
      "Global Business Partners",
      "Global Financing",
      "Client Support IT",
      "Automation & Tooling",
      "Toolbox@IBM",
    ]
  }
}
```

I am doing like this:

```js
itemsToFilter.map(i => i.domain_name)
```

And i want all values just of `domain_name`

But the result is:

[image]

Comment: _And i want all values just of domain_name..._ `itemsToFilter.map(i => ('domain_name'))`?

Comment: Can you elaborate more about your expected output

Comment: @hindmost @front_end_dev I want just the value of `domain_name`, but it gives a array with the values of `domain_name` and `undefined` that would be the `subdomain_name`

Comment: You want `itemsToFilter[0].domain_name`

Comment: Why don't you have domain_name and subdomain_name as different properties of the same object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue is in your variable name: items to **filter**.

You want to **filter** the array, not **map** every item in it onto a different value.

```js
itemsToFilter = [{
    "domain_name": [
      "Sales and Marketing Systems",
      "Finance and Supply Chain",
      "Global Infrastructure & CIO Services",
      "Systems and Tools",
      "Quote to Cash & Services",
      "Network Engineering",
      "CFO",
      "Cloud, Collaboration, Support & Identity",
      "Digital Workplace Engineering",
      "CIO Design",
      "Confidential",
      "CIO Domain"
    ]
  },
  {
    "subdomain_name": [
      "Territory, Quota and Coverage",
      "Analytics@IBM",
      "CIO Business Development",
      "HW/SW Manufacturing and Plan to Supply",
      "Virtualisation and Data Center Platforms",
      "HR Talent & Travel IT",
      "Quote to Cash and Services",
      "Finance",
      "CIO Services Japan",
      "Global Business Partners",
      "Global Financing",
      "Client Support IT",
      "Automation & Tooling",
      "Toolbox@IBM",
    ]
  }
];

const filteredItems = itemsToFilter.filter(item => "domain_name" in item);

console.log(filteredItems);
```

Comment: Thank you ver much for your answer... but i have a question,,, if I want to filter the values ​​of it now, for example return only the value that contains the phrase `Confidential`, using include, how do I do this?